# Playing Internet Explorer system sounds from a VB6 application with the winmm.dll library

Tags: vb6

My declaration goes:

```
Private Declare Function PlaySound Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "PlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszName _
As String, ByVal hModule As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
```

I'm using the code:

```
PlaySound Text2.Text, 0, &H1
```

Text2 is a textbox on my Form that I'm using to experiment with different sound aliases.

It works well for Windows default sounds (aliase such "SystemAsterisk", "SystemStart", "WindowsLogOn", "DeviceConnect", etc...), but how can I make my app play Explorer sounds?

In the registry, default sounds are stored like this:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default\DeviceConnect\.Default
```

If I pass "DeviceConnect" to the Playsound function, it plays the right sound. But how can I reach sounds that are stored in other branches of the tree? For example:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\Explorer\Navigating\.Default
```

I googled for hours, but still no solution. Thanks a lot for your help!

Davide

PS: I know I could just copy the sounds I want into my application folder, but I'm trying to tick to a single executable file for easier distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Navigating example you have is an application-specific sound.  Unfortunately, the SND_APPLICATION flag that you can pass to the PlaySound() call will only work with your application.

There are a couple of ways to play this sound in your own application:

- Read the filename from the registry and play the sound as a file.
- Create your own application-specific definition in the registry (copying the filename from the Explorer reg key) and use the SND_APPLICATION and SND_ALIAS flags to play it.  You will have to set the reg value every time your program starts if you always want it to match the Explorer version.
- Since you don't want to include multiple files with your program, you could embed the sound as a resource in the application and use the SND_RESOURCE flag to play it.  I'll note that if the user changes the Navigating sound in the Control Panel, your sound won't match if you do this.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your excellent reply! Very clear and exhaustive! Sorry it took me long to accept it!
I tried the first solution you mentioned, but my result was not very consistent across platforms. I must have made some mistakes. I'll try number 3, it looks the most straigthforward and I certainly do NOT want it to change is the user changes the settings. Thanks a lot!
PS: any further advice on how to do option 3 is more than welcome!